# jQuery UI strange resize behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a div which is resizable from the left (w) and the right (e) using jQuery UI. Resizing on the right works perfectly, but on the left two things behave different:

1. I can't resize the element to 0 width
2. It jumps when resizing starts

I made this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ocsuro9u/1/)

```
$("#test").resizable({
    handles: 'e,w',
    grid: 32,
    maxWidth: null,
    minWidth: 0
});
```

Why is that so?

Thanks

**Edit**
Grid 32 is needed, but you are right, it would work without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I overwrite jQuery UI's `$.ui.plugin.add("resizable", "grid")` on resize `start`.
Not the best solution I think but it works.

Here you can see the changes I made in the last `if-else`:

**Old:**

```
if ( newWidth - gridX > 0 ) {
    that.size.width = newWidth;
    that.position.left = op.left - ox;
} else {
    that.size.width = gridX;
    that.position.left = op.left + os.width - gridX;
}
```

**Customised:**

```
if ( newWidth - gridX >= 0 ) {
    that.size.width = newWidth;
    that.position.left = op.left - ox;
} else {
    that.size.width = o.minWidth;
    that.position.left = op.left + os.width - gridX;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove grid: 32. It causes the problem you are facing.

Comment: If you use that then it will not allow you to resize it to zero.